# Substituting an expression with sympy

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I have the following expression :

```
p/l
```

which I extract from a matrix. I later define p and l with following code

```
from sympy.abc import c,G,M,J,l,u,v,w
us = (2*G*M/c**2)
a = (J/(M*c))
p = (u**2 + a**2*cos(v))
l = (u**2 - us*u + a**2)
```

I want to substitute the expression `p/l` and describe it instead with all of the expressions above. I tried doing the following. If g is a sympy.Matrix object and the first element is defined as `p/l`, then

```
g[0,0].subs([(p,u**2 + a**2*cos(v)),(l,u**2 - us*u + a**2)])
```

should do the trick, yet instead I still get `p/l`, the expression remains unchanged. If I simply type `p/l` in an ipython session, I get the output

```
(J**2*cos(v)/(M**2*c**2) + u**2)/(-2*G*M*u/c**2 + J**2/(M**2*c**2) + u**2)
```

Which is what I desire. (Well almost, I would prefer applying simplify on it first as such : `(J**2*cos(v) + M**2*c**2*u**2)/(-2*G*M**3*u + J**2 + M**2*c**2*u**2)` ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are substituting expressions with identical expressions, the result of the substitution is thus identical to the original expression.

Make sure not to confuse SymPy symbols and Python variables:

```
# Python variable: `p` stores an addition object:
p = (u**2 + a**2*cos(v))

# SymPy symbol, it's just a symbol, no expressions:
p = Symbol('p')

# express symbol-expression relation in some way, like:
{p: (u**2 + a**2*cos(v))}
```

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to comment that since the expressions I listed above are inter-dependent, I had to make sure that I substituted in the correct order: `us,p,a,l = symbols('us,p,a,l');
    g = g.subs({p:u**2 + a**2*cos(v)});
    g = g.subs({l:u**2 - us*u + a**2});
    g = g.subs({us:2*G*M/c**2});
    g = g.subs({a:J/(M*c)});
    g = simplify(g)`